# How can I reduce the hard disk space occupied by "Other"?

Tags: macos, hard-drive

On my internal hard disk "Other" (as shown in "About this Mac") is using 167.99 GB of 251 GB.

I already used Daisy Disk and removed 30 GB (it was 200 GB before).
How can I further reduce it?

Comment: Have you already removed iTunes old backups?

Comment: Have you run Daisy Disk with administrator privilages? If you are using Xcode it can consume a lot of space with Derived Data or Device Information.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202867) is an article explaining what the "Other" category of files is, from Apple support. Basically, the Other folder is anything that cannot be recognized as Audio, Video, Photos, Apps, and Backups. If you want to free up some space in here, you need to navigate to your home folder, and move any files to the Trash that you don't need. Then, empty the trash. If there are still files taking up a lot of space that you really need, you can compress them. (Create a folder, place the files in the folder, and click "Compress ." You can also transfer some files to an external drive.

Also, here is an [iGeeksBlog article](http://www.igeeksblog.com/what-is-other-on-mac-how-to-remove/) giving some more tips on how to remove things from the Other folder.